# Target a Container with Sencha Touch 2 FormPanel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How do I tell touch to place a form in a specific container?

**Current:**

```
<body>
    <div>hey there</div>
    <div id="formContainer"></div>
    <div>the end</div>
    **TOUCH ALWAYS APPENDS EXT-VIEWPORT TO THE END OF THE BODY**
</body>
```

**Desired:**

```
<body>
    <div>hey there</div>
    <div id="formContainer">**APPEND HERE INSTEAD**</div>
    <div>the end</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

cause the Viewport will always render to the `<body>`.
you need a `Ext.Container` with `renderTo: Ext.get('#formContainer')`.

Comment: Could you point me to a code sample where I can see this? I'm a sencha n00b.

Comment: Please post first what you have so far.  Then I can help you.